# Illegal constructor with EcmaScript 6

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

First of all I would like that say that I don't really know how I can explain what I did on order to get the error mentioned in the title (`uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`). I am using gulpfile in order to compile my Ecmascript 6 to plain Javascript. My gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('compile', function () {
    return gulp.src(['resources/assets/js/*.js', 'resources/assets/js/components/*.js'])
        .pipe(babel({
                presets: ['es2015']
        }).on('error', logError))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
   gulp.watch('resources/assets/js/**/*', ['compile']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

function logError(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

I have a filesystem where all files are concatenated to one file (bundle.js), after being compiled with Babel.

In the browsers console (either Chrome or Firefox), the error appears and it is located in the next line:

```
var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Dropdown.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Dropdown)).call(this, element));
```

[image: The error within the console]

This is the non-compiled code of this:

```
class Dropdown extends Node {

    constructor(element) {
        super(element);

        this.registerEvents(['click', 'change', 'blur']);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.$element.addClass('clicked');
    }
}
```

And this is the compiled code of the same class:

```
var Dropdown = function (_Node) {
    _inherits(Dropdown, _Node);

    function Dropdown(element) {
        _classCallCheck(this, Dropdown);

        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Dropdown.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Dropdown)).call(this, element));

        _this.registerEvents(['click', 'change', 'blur']);

        return _this;
    }

    _createClass(Dropdown, [{
        key: 'onClick',
        value: function onClick() {
            this.$element.addClass('clicked');
        }
    }]);

    return Dropdown;
}(Node);
```

I am not using `export default Dropdown` because I am not importing modules in other modules (this is not needed because every file is converted to one file, where everything is accessible).

I did some research and the only reason why peoeple got this error was because there was a capital letter where none was allowed. I didn't find anything else about the cause of this error. Does someone have an idea why I get this error? And does someone have a solution?

Comment: What is `Node`? If it's DOM's `Node`, you cannot extend that in JavaScript.

Comment: If you can't instantiate `Node` (and you can't), you obviously can't instantiate child class too.

Comment: Do you need to import the file you need to extend or is it also ok if the class that has to be extended is defined in the same file (so without `export default superClass`)?

Comment: @Galago: It's absolutely fine if it's defined in the same file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to extend DOM's [`Node`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node). You can't do that, it's defined as an abstract interface, and the host-provided function exposed in browsers for it can't be called as a constructor (even by subclasses).

Comment: Thanks, missed adding `import { Node } from 'tiptap'`, so it used the global `Node` definition instead.

Answer (score 59):

This is the first Google result for this error message and it also frequently comes up in conjunction with web components. With a perfectly valid looking web component like this:

```
export default class UserAvatar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

You will get this error if you forget to call `customElements.define` and try to instantiate the component.

So, `new UserAvatar` will fail with *Illegal constructor*. To fix it, define it first:

`customElements.define('tom-user-avatar', UserAvatar);`

It's a bad error message in both Firefox and Chrome, the browser vendors should do a better job here. If you're using `document.createElement` instead of `new UserAvatar` you will likely catch this quickly though, because it will remind you that you haven't set up the name. There are reasons for initiating custom elements with a constructor though, like passing in initialization parameters.

Comment: Absolutely astonishing response, thank you!

Comment: This was the problem I was facing. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I encountered the same error with Web Components but only on Safari (not Firefox). Cause was that I did a `class UserAvatar extends HTMLSpanElement` (rather than `HTMLElement`).

Comment: but uh... what if I'm not trying to create a web component?

Comment: Then you are perhaps looking for the other answer to this question or are having an issue which is not covered by either answer yet, in which case you should post a new question with all the relevant detail.

Comment: I don't know why this is not the accepted answer ... thanks for your help ...