# Can't call class properties inside inline script tag

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript class inside my global.js like this:

```js
class CustomModal extends ModalDialog {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.modals = [{
                name: 'quick-select',
                title: 'Quick Select',
            },
            {
                name: 'main-menu',
                title: 'Menu',
            },
            {
                name: 'notify-me',
                title: 'Notify When Back in Stock',
            },
        ];
    }
}

window.CustomModal = CustomModal;
```

Now I want to access the class properties from outside the class inside an inline script tag, like this:

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log('window.CustomModal.modals', window.CustomModal.modals)
    });
</script>
```

but I'm getting `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?
I want to access properties and functions. I also want to change variables. My main goal is to add another modal to the array, like this:

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        window.CustomModal.modals.push({ name: 'new-modal', title: 'New Modal' });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `class`, hence you should instantiate it:

```
window.CustomModal = new CustomModal();
```

In your attempt, you only set a reference of the prototype of that class.

Comment: Thank you. Should I add this inside the global.js? Because I'm getting "Illegal constructor"

Comment: I'm afraid that there's more behind, then. I don't see reasons for such error. Could you disclose more code, that is about the `CustomModal` window's field?

Comment: The error gets called at "new ModalDialog" and "new CustomModal" at the line `super()` inside the constructor. `class ModalDialog extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); ...` and `class CustomModal extends ModalDialog {
    constructor() {
      super(); ...` after I added this line inside my global.js `window.CustomModal = new CustomModal();`. I also define CustomModal as a custom element, if that's relevant. Like this: `if (!customElements.get('custom-modal'))
  customElements.define('custom-modal', CustomModal);`

Comment: I believe you should read the answer to this post. It looks the same problem you have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521812/illegal-constructor-with-ecmascript-6